# SQL query not yielding correct result

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause, natural-join

The goal of the following SQL query is to return the name and salary for each female manager who lives in San Fran or LA. I am confused as to why this query is returning male managers as well as female managers... I would have initially thought that defining the constraint "gender = 'F'" along with the natural join would have gotten rid of all the male manager listings right away.

```
select Lastname, FirstName, MidInitial, salary, gender
  from Employee natural join Works natural join Manages
where Lastname = ManagerLastname and
FirstName = MFirstName and
MidInitial = MMidInitial and
gender = 'F' and
city = 'San Fran' or city = 'LA';

--RESULT:
LASTNAME    FIRSTNAME   MIDINITIAL  SALARY  GENDER
Brandy      Dan         L           42000   M
Clemson     Ann         M           39000   F
Gill        Mary        L           48700   F
Simon       Eric        K           45000   M
```

Does anyone see anything inherently wrong with the above query? FYI: Here is the schema for this database's tables:

```
create table Employee(
    Lastname    varchar(10),
    FirstName   varchar(10),
    MidInitial  char(1),
    gender      char(1),
    street      varchar(10),
    city        varchar(10),
    primary key(Lastname, FirstName, MidInitial));

create table company(
    company_name    varchar(20),
    city    varchar(10),
    primary key(company_name));

create table Works(
    Lastname    varchar(10),
    FirstName   varchar(10),
    MidInitial  char(1),
    company_name    varchar(20),
    salary      numeric(8,2),
    primary key(Lastname, FirstName, MidInitial, company_name),
    foreign key(Lastname, FirstName, MidInitial) references Employee,
    foreign key(company_name) references company);

create table Manages(
    Lastname    varchar(10),
    FirstName   varchar(10),
    MidInitial  char(1),
    ManagerLastname varchar(10),
    MFirstName  varchar(10),
    MMidInitial char(1),
    start_date  date,
    primary key(Lastname, FirstName, MidInitial, ManagerLastname, MFirstName, MMidInitial),
    foreign key(Lastname, FirstName, MidInitial) references Employee);
```

Also, I am using SQL for Oracle 11g R2.

Thanks for taking a look at this!

Comment: try grouping your condition `Lastname = ManagerLastname and
FirstName = MFirstName and
MidInitial = MMidInitial and
gender = 'F' and
(city = 'San Fran' or city = 'LA')` or instead of using `OR` use `IN` eg `Lastname = ManagerLastname and
FirstName = MFirstName and
MidInitial = MMidInitial and
gender = 'F' and
city = ('San Fran','LA')`

Answer (score 2):

The trouble is that `AND` has a higher precedence than `OR`.

So your query says, in effect:

> Show me all records where **Lastname = ManagerLastname** and **FirstName = MFirstName** and **MidInitial = MMidInitial** and **gender = 'F'** and **city = 'San Fran'**

*-- or --*

> **city = 'LA'**

What you want is:

```
where Lastname = ManagerLastname and
FirstName = MFirstName and
MidInitial = MMidInitial and
gender = 'F' and
( city = 'San Fran' or city = 'LA' )
```